# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Hospital\Patient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Hospital\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

this is the error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Hospital\Patient' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Hospital\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Hospital\index.php on line 7

this is index.php

```
<?php

require ("vendor/autoload.php");

use Hospital\Patient;

$patient = new Patient("asd","ad","asd","asd","asd");

var_dump($patient);
```

this is patient.php

```
<?php

namespace Hospital;

class Patient extends Person
{
     public function __construct($name, $age, $eyecolor, $height, $weight)
     {
        parent::__construct($name, $age, $eyecolor, $height, $weight);
     }
 }
```

and this is composer.json

```
{
  "autoload":{
   "psr-4":{
    "Hospital//": ""
   }
  }
}
```

can someone pleas tell me what i'm doing wrong?
if you miss information please tell me, i'm new to this.

Comment: Check proper spacing in near php statement .                                           
<?php

require ("vendor/autoload.php");

Comment: try running `php composer.phar dump-autoload`  in your terminal

Comment: and then `php composer.phar install` may be this both will help